# I can't work with columns of df created from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary, request

i have json request which i convert by using `json()` to list of dictionaries. no problem to create a df from this list, I can’t understand why I can’t work with columns, I try to select some columns and I get error:
`"None of [Index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3' dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`
i can get column names by `print(list(df))` and everything is fine, but when i try `loc` or `df = df[['col1']]` it gives me error.
then i put df to excel and take it back, everything works, i think may be `copy()` help, but not

i need to take a column

```
get_request = requests.get(url, headers=token)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(get_request.json()[par], orient = "columns")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simple `fillna()`, I don’t understand the mechanics, but the problem was in Nan values, they didn’t let me work with df